# <Link> tag producing error: React.createElement: type is invalid

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Error in React Router's link tag while switching from 0.14 to v15.5. This worked fine in the former version and it throws the following error in the latter.

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `Navbar`.

**navbar.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Link from 'react-router-dom';

class Navbar extends Component
{
  render()
  {
     return (

         <nav className="nav">                                         
           <Link className="btn btn-primary btn-block" to="/about">
           About Us
           </Link>
         </nav>

     );
  }

  export default Navbar;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import HomePage from './components/homepage/homepage';
import AboutPage from './components/aboutpage/aboutpage';

render
(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
            <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: you have not defined any class in index.js.did u?

Comment: no, it's just as it's shown here.

Comment: are you using navbar in some other component that you have not mentioned in your question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this error generally comes if you have not imported or exported a component successfully in your components.For more more info you can read react documentation of when to use curly braces while import and when not:)

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

.

```
<ul>
  <li><Link to="x">x</Link></li>
  <li><Link to="y">y</Link></li>
  <li><Link to="z">z</Link></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, Vikram. This still yields the same error. Currently, I'm not using `navbar` or `Link tag` anywhere else in my app.

Comment: yes as i mentioned in my earlier comment you might be using navbar in some component but you have not exported your navbar component in that component.thats why you are getting this error

Comment: My sincere apologies. Actually, I did so in the app but forgot to add it here. I've updated the question.

Comment: Thanks a ton, Vikram. That was the error. I was missing the curly braces in the `Link` tag. But it needs to be imported from `react-router-dom` and not `react-router`. Please update your answer.